# Clean up Play-framework based project

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

After running a new `Play-framework 2.0` based project, i failed to clean it - the generated staff persisted below,

```
 $ play new myapp
   > app name: myapp
   > template: java app

myapp/
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   └── views
├── conf
├── project
└── public
    ├── images
    ├── javascripts
    └── stylesheets

$ cd myapp
$ play
  [myapp] run 12345
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

```
  [myapp] clean

myapp/
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   └── views
├── conf
├── logs
├── project
│   ├── project
│   │   └── target
│   │       └── config-classes
│   └── target
│       ├── scala-2.9.1
│       │   └── sbt-0.11.2
│       │       ├── cache
│       │       │   ├── compile
│       │       │   └── update
│       │       └── classes
│       └── streams
│           ├── compile
│           │   ├── compile
│           │   │   └── $global
│           │   ├── compile-inputs
│           │   │   └── $global
│           │   ├── copy-resources
│           │   │   └── $global
│           │   ├── defined-sbt-plugins
│           │   │   └── $global
│           │   └── $global
│           │       └── $global
│           └── $global
│               ├── compilers
│               │   └── $global
│               ├── ivy-configuration
│               │   └── $global
│               ├── ivy-sbt
│               │   └── $global
│               ├── project-descriptors
│               │   └── $global
│               └── update
│                   └── $global
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
└── target
```

How can i succeed in cleaning it up?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
play clean-all
```

See http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/PlayConsole

Comment: `clean-all` is no longer working with newer versions.

Answer (score 18):

`clean-all` no longer works.
All you need :

```
activator clean-files
```

See : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/PlayConsole