# Java Play! Startup Problems

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

When I first ran eclipsify on my Project I noticed that Eclipse complained about the:

```
return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
```

Line. It did not recognize the index method. The application still ran so I ignored it for the time being. Now, however, I am getting a new error. I think I just added a few dependencies to Mongo, attached some Model files and rebuilt but I am now getting this error:

> compile: sbt.InvalidComponent: Could not find required component 'compiler-interface-src'

I'm not sure why this is happening, especially because I'm a bit of a sbt idiot. As a side note, Eclipse is reporting that my "classes_managed" build path entry is missing, but I think that is due to my inability to compile after doing a clean. (Clean and update are working).

Comment: I solved the problem by deleting play and reinstalling it. Not sure what happened, but that "fix" worked for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Templates are compiled by Play, not by eclipse. After the "eclipsify", you need to run `play compile` (or `play run`) and refresh your eclipse project. See [How to make Eclipse see the changes in Play! compiled templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042987/how-to-make-eclipse-see-the-changes-in-play-compiled-templates)

2) After adding dependencies, launch a new time the `play eclipsify` command.
But i think it's not the problem. **What is the dependency you add ? And what is your Play2 version?** (I suspect an incompatibility with a Play2.1 library)

And for your information, a general rule: Play doesn't depend on Eclipse to compile files. Do not try to clean in eclipse, but run `play clean` (and refresh eclipse).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback- in the end, reinstalling worked for me but you get a check for the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Happen to run into this issue few times, tried above, also following
[Clean up Play-framework based project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841024/clean-up-play-framework-based-project)

But nothing worked.

What it turned out to be was a IntelliJ Idea **cache corruption** issue, and *invalidate and restart* Idea worked fine.