# Play 2.4.3 app file structure is malformed

Tags: java, playframework, target, typesafe-activator

I'm migrating my play app to another machine and I can't get it set up quite right.  I installed activator.  But it seems to be putting files in weird places.

I'm aware that there should be a bunch of files under /target/, such as src_managed, classes_managed.  But instead, I only see /target/streams/.  I also see /project/target/{all the files} and /project/project/{all the files}.  Anytime I move the fodlers, activator clean puts it back the wrong way

I checked my classpath and found the following line:

```
classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/PATH/TO/target/scala-2.11/classes"/>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?  I'm pretty desperate at this point.

EDIT:  I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841024/clean-up-play-framework-based-project) with my exact problem, but the solution didn't work for me:

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to run `activator all-dependencies`.  So I did that then `activator clean-files`.  Then `activator eclipse`.  But it didn't fix the unresolved views problem I was having.